# Necromancer badge description

Tags: feature-request, badges

This is less of a question than an observation. Much to my surprise, I was awarded a Necromancer badge today, for no action of mine. The mouse-over on the badge says

> Answered a question more than 60 days later with a score of 5 or more.

What actually happened was that I had answered a question in June and someone upvoted it today. Trying to reverse-engineer what went on led me to think that the badge description would be more accurate if it were something along the lines of

> Received a score of 5 or more on an answer that was more than 60 days old.

Nit-picky I know but after all, mathematicians are supposed to be nit-picky. (Now I have to figure out how to tag this puppy.)

Comment: Now try and parse: "Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses" (:

Comment: @Douglas Or the description of `Populist` -- "Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x". There should be a badge for writing descriptions like that.

Comment: -1 because your interpretation is incorrect. What happened was that you _did_ answer a question that was 60+ days old when you answered it. That you got the badge today is because you finally got the fifth vote.

Comment: @Douglas There _is_ a way for SE to track that, btw. If you share a link using the "share" button on the bottom of posts the URL string includes your user ID on MSE, so the system can keep a tally of number of links generated by you. Note that if you just copy the URL from the address bar of your web browser, you will miss out on that.

Comment: @Pavel: heh, parentheses to the rescue? "[Highest scoring answer] that [outscored an (accepted answer with score more than 10) by more than 2x]". Reminds me of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293?lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your interpretation is incorrect. You did not get the badge because your answer was 60 days old when it was upvoted. You got it because the question (which is from 2011) was more than 60 days old when you answered it. The badge description puts it right: answered more than 60 days after the question was asked.

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

**Edit:** @DumbCow raised the issue of whether 60 days are counted from the posting of the question or from the last activity on the question (which includes edits and answers). To clarify this, I looked up the history of über-necromancer [Matt E](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/17/necromancer?userid=221). The following are among the answers for which he earned the badge:

- [CW answer dated by May 1 '11 at 22:39](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/36290/53153); another answer was posted same day at 15:52.
- [Answer dated by May 10 '12](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143337/53153); the question was edited on May 4 '12.
- [Answer dated by Jun 26 '12 at 2:22](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163114/53153); another answer was posted same day at 1:35.

I conclude that 60 days are counted from the time the question is originally posted.

---

Bonus content: the related bronze badge `Revival` has an additional restriction: your answer must reach a score of 2 before any earlier answer to the same question reaches a score of 2. (This is tersely worded as "Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more"). This restriction still allows a possibility of two users "reviving" the same question, if an older answer reaches the score of 2 later than newer. The description of `Necromancer` does not contain such a restriction.

Comment: Downvoted per request [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/notice-question-on-number-of-known-digits-of-pi-re-opened-now-locked#comment26357_7154)

Comment: @Martin Thanks. To other users: I hope this question will stay with <10 upvotes, for the sake of a long-term experiment.

Comment: -1 glad to help...delete it when you reach - 3 for a peer pressure experiment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add upon the explanation of Pavel M.  As I type out this answer, I see that when the question's title is seen in the list of questions, at the bottom-right is written `4h ago Pavel M 3,292`. Notice the timestamp `4h ago` which denotes when this question was **last active**. The Necromancer badge is received when the question had last activity **60 days or more back**. Note that “activity” includes:

- edits to questions/answers.
- answers

Comment: Then the Meta.SO source to which I linked must be wrong, because it  says "60 days after the question was posted". This merits an investigation.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the point you raised.